# Tool for EER Modeling

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, conceptual-model, eer-model

Is there a good free conceptual modeling tool for EER modeling? It should support specialization, generalizaton, union, etc. I came across MySQL Workbench but it seemed to belong to the physical modeling stage(examples that I saw included 'VARCHAR' or 'INTEGER' specifications for attributes and it deals with tables rather than entities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Open System Architect](http://www.codebydesign.com)** is brilliant.

[**SQL Power Architect**](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect) .
 It's community edition is free, and does a really great job helping you build your ERDs.
 It works on Windows, Linux, and OSX.